# How to remove the brackets from list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```py
list1 = ['[0', '"properties"', '"ipv4"', '0', '"value"]']
```

I want the output:

```py
list1= 0 , "properties" , "ipv4" , 0 , "value"
```

I have tried:

```py
ini_string = ini_string.replace('[', '').replace(']','')
```

But it is giving an output like:

```
> 0 
> query_json2 = query_json2[ini_string] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: list1 contains a single string. Are you sure you typed it correctly? If so, then why not just print the string inside? Edit: seems like it has more than one strings, the formatting confused me.

Comment: yes..its correct. i just want to replace only the brackets from that. and get output like this : 0 , "properties" , "ipv4" , 0 , "value"

Comment: @Vidhya I think, Length of your List is 5, will you please is confirm that, `len(list1)`

Comment: you can use [strip](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html), along with [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html) , if your `[`,`]` and `"` are only at the begining/ end of each string. `list1 = [x.strip('[').strip(']').strip('"') for x in list1]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
list1 = ['[0', '"properties"', '"ipv4"', '0', '"value"]']
a = [a.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for a in list1]
b = ', '.join(a)
print(b)
```

Let's assume if you are iterate via dictionary. So after the above code.

```
some_dict = {
    0: {
        'properties': {
            'ipv4': {
                0: {
                    'value': 'new_value'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for x in a:
    if x.isdigit():
        new = some_dict[int(x)]
    else:
        x = x.replace('"', '')
        new = some_dict[x]
    some_dict = new


print(some_dict)
```

Comment: thank you! this worked. but i need one more help. i want to make it like
query_json[0]['properties']['macAddr'][0]['value']. So i have tried like this 
query_json2 = query_json[b] 
return query_json2
But the output i got is 

0, "properties", "ipv4", 0, "value"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/collector-test/dnaci-medley/medley/helpers/ndp/services/controllerserver/controllerserver_service.py", line 271, in parse_json
    query_json2 = query_json2[b]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: can you please help me here @Govinda

Comment: What are you filtering? Is it a dictionary?

Comment: I updated the code. Check whether is it along what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
result = ''
for word in list1:
  cleanWord = ''.join(re.split('[|]'))
  result += cleanWord + ' ,'
print("list 1 = " + result[:-2])
```

Essentially you strip it of `[` and `]` and append it to a string to output

Answer (score 0):

Try this out....

````
list1 = ['[0', '"properties"', '"ipv4"', '0', '"value"]']
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    if "[" in list1[i] or "]" in list1[i]:
        list1[i] = re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', list1[i])
print(",".join(list1))```
````